How can reflected blast pressure and impulse be several times incident?
So, I used this Kingery-Bulmash blast parameter calculator, and got the following results:
TNT Weight for Pressure (kg):   1.00
TNT Weight for Impulse (kg):    1.00
Incident Pressure (kPa):    1356.74
Incident Impulse (kPa-ms):  236.43
Reflected Pressure (kPa):   8144.95
Reflected Impulse (kPa-ms): 884.77
That doesn't make sense. I would expect am amplifying cation of 2 or less from reflection. But here we have like 6. It's like the wave triples in power upon reflection. What's going on here?

Here is an easy way to visualize this.
Imagine a big water wave striking an immovable stone pier in a harbor. The wave smacks into the pier and its height shoots up a distance that greatly exceeds the initial height of the wave but for only an instant and only right next to the pier surface.
Look up Richard Serber's book The Los Alamos Primer. In it he furnishes a derivation of the maximum pressure gain contained in a supersonic shock wave. To first order the gain factor happens to be ~6, which I think is related to your question.
